# Multiple lines of text in UILabel in iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios9

I`m working on an iOS project but when I updated to iOS 9 I had some problem with multiline in UILabels. I'm using **Autolayout**.

**Anybody knows how to do it in iOS 9 ?**

I tried different ways such as:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

(from other similar question) but it did not work.

This is my logic to show multilines:

IB config:

[image: preferedMaxLayout]

[image]

[image: label config]

I update this value programmatically:

```
- (void)configureLabelsMaxLayoutWidth
{
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.titleLabel.frame);
}
```

I call this method on the **viewWillAppear**

Comment: What happens exactly? I have similar labels working in iOS 9.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using AutoLayout and are not constraining the width of the label? It will only wrap the label if it can't make the label long enough. If the label can be made long enough then the label will always take 1 line.

Comment: I'm setting the preferedMaxLa.... :  self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.titleLabel.frame), but the result is the same. I have one line with "..." at the end.

Comment: How are you creating the label? Are you using AutoLayout? Are you using frames? etc. etc...

Comment: Peter DeWeese, how do toy get multiline in iOS 9 ? What did you do ?

Comment: You may add text with newline chars, like this: @"line1\nline2" and then resize frame of the label to text size. I do it in this way.

Comment: I'm using Autolayout. Thanks for teh response Skippy, bit I want that the label "cut" the text according the a max width. My actual implementation works in iOS 7 /8, the problem is with iOS 9 :(

Comment: I have updated the question with my logic to show multilines (that does not work in iOS 9). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

By setting `numberOfLines` to `0` you're telling the label to be multiline, however there may be other factors disabling multilines. Are you using autolayout? If so, that problem may be that the labels `Content Compression Resistance Priority` is too low, try setting it to `Required` or `1000`.

The content compression resistance tells the view engine at what priority your label can shrink. Setting it to required forces it to not shrink.

In Interface Builder, simply select the label, tap `Size Inspector` (the little ruler) and then change it to 1000.
[image]

Or, in code, the equivalent would be:

```
[label setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I did your suggestion but it did not work. :(

Answer (score 3):

After setting up constraints, remember `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = superview.bounds.size.width - 20
```

Comment: Worked for me! On iOS 10 there's no issue and it works with the designed autolayout configuration. On iOS 9 I had to add this preferredMaxLayoutWidth option..

Answer (score 1):

**(Swift 4, xCode 9.3.1)** I know this will not apply to everyone that crosses this answer but hopefully it helps someone. My situation was that I have a UIScrollView bound to the superview. I wanted to add a UILabel with lots of text to the ScrollView with equal width so it only scrolls vertically. Basically I wanted a vertically-scrolling UILabel bound to the superview. I ran into the problem that the UILabel was staying one line even after setting numberOfLines to zero.

This was the code in my ViewController I used to make this work.

```
class DetailsController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
    didSet {
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.addSubview(detailsLabel)
    }
}

var detailsLabel = UILabel()

let detailsText = "Insert lots of text here"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    detailsLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    detailsLabel.text = detailsText + detailsText
    detailsLabel.frame.size.width = (scrollView?.frame.size.width)!
    detailsLabel.sizeToFit()
    scrollView?.contentSize = detailsLabel.frame.size
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I needed to call layoutIfNeeded() at the end:

```
textLabel.text = "your loooooooong text"
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
textLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
```